# Update jails FreeBSD in silent mode

Tags: freebsd, upgrade, jails

What if I want to add all process to the cron? Is there silent way to upgrade jail?

After these steps:

```
# make buildworld       
# make installworld DESTDIR=/jails/somejail
```

It comes time to:

```
# mergemaster -Ui -D /jails/somejail
```

How to automate this process as asking so many questions during this operation (mean mergemaster) ? I want all my config files to stay untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving all your config files untouched can be a dangerous thing. Therefore, I'd advise against doing that. That said, there is an option for mergemaster to deal with everything automatically. From the `mergemaster(8)` manpage:

> ```
> -a     Run automatically.  This option will leave all the files that
>        differ from the installed versions in the temporary directory
>        to be dealt with by hand.  If the temproot directory exists,
>        it creates a new one in a previously non-existent directory.
>        This option unsets the verbose flag, and is not compatible
>        with -i, -F, or -U.  Setting -a makes -w superfluous.
> ```

If you want to automate handling jails, you might however want to take a closer look at all the jail management thingies out there, like `ezjail` and `qjail`. These already provide automatisms to deal with updating jails.